# Set app icon to facebook invite dialog

Tags: android, facebook

[image]

I am using facebook app invite. Everything is fine. But I don't know how to set my app icon.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to change the icon in the facebook developer console.
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/2898989898/settings/basic/

Comment: Uploaded 1024 X1024 size image, but still not visible in share invite dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Go on [developer.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com), go on settings, there you will have the option to change app icon in the dialog.